# WordPress shortcode return syntax

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, shortcode

I am trying to output some HTML/PHP with a shortcode function in WordPress.
The problem I have is the syntax, where I need to mix HTML and PHP in the output. But I have no idea how to separate it properly.

```
function email_shortcode() {
    return '<a class="email" href="mailto:jobs@company.com?Subject='echo get_field("jo-title") get_field("jo-location")'">Email us</a>';
}
add_shortcode('email', 'email_shortcode');
```

Anyone have a proper solution for the return output?

Comment: You can not use `echo` there, you need to do simple string concatenation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code should look like this.

```
function email_shortcode() {
    return '<a class="email" href="mailto:jobs@company.com?Subject='.get_field("jo-title") .' '.get_field("jo-location").'">Email us</a>';
}
add_shortcode('email', 'email_shortcode');
```